# Compilation Failure

Tags: java, maven

I have been getting compilation failure when using maven install command. I am sharing my pom.xml and the error.It also looks like the tests are getting executed from the src/main/java class and not from the src/test/java.

`Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>tiger</groupId>
  <artifactId>Tiger</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Tiger</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

   <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>

          <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>

        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

The error when I am getting  using mvn install is as follows:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTsZ.png)

Comment: It isn't able to find your package `MyHomepageTestCases`

Comment: Please add errors as text, not as image, it is then indexable by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

You probably reference your test from the code in `src/main/java`, you can't do that. It might compile in Eclipse (if you use that), but not with maven.

Please post the source code for `Home.java`. The `pom.xml` is irrelevant.

Also, [by convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), package names should be all lower case. Nearly all java developers follow this.